# PTC thermistor simulation in Proteus

Tags: proteus, thermistor, ptc

I want to simulate PTC thermistor in Proteus, but I need this informations.

1. Thermal Contact Res. (°C/W)
2. Thermal Res. to Ambient (°C/W)
3. Time constant (s)

[image]

full datasheet:

http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2050662.pdf?_ga=2.261979140.845161386.1546173081-1474740581.1524733191

How can I reach variable values in 1,2 and 3 from datasheet?

Answer (score 1):

The time constant is variable.

1s if  It/Int= 5,
6s if It/Int=2.5 and
**35s if It/Int=1.3** which is the

**From external self heating hot air it appears to be >>35s,** which is the lowest trip ratio given for 5mm and all sizes.

It is a self heating PTC not a temperature measuring sensor.
The time constant is a function of the Trip current **It** over the non-trip rated current **Int.** or **It/Int**

The Dissip. Factor (DF) for the 5mmD part is 7.3 (mW/K) therefore the **Rja= 1/DF = 137 ('C/W)**

The voltage derating is 100% from  75'C to 175'C therefore the **trip temp is 175'C** with a 100'C swing .  But if the Pd were known to be 0.75W at trip temp, the Rca would be 100'C/W/0.75W = **133 ('C/W)** but we do not know this Pd. as it is not exactly constant

> I want to ask 2 more questions. 1)If R=11 ohm in 25 °C and Iolmax =1500 (max overload current),then **How can i calculate lolmax in 50 °C** ?What is the formula? 2)If R=11 ohm in 25 °C,then **how can i calculate R in 50 °C and in other temperatures?** What is the formula?

You have to know how to create a formula from the curves given in your datasheet on pages 2 and 5. Now since these are not specified as a formula, you need a really good reason to do this and a better understanding of uncertainty and errors in this calculation.

If you see the curves on these pages, you may be surprised to learn that the

### **PTC actually has an NTC curve below 85'C**

and then it flattens out and turns upwards to PTC.
[image]

The slope from 25'C to 75'C = k (Log R)/T   **where k is the negative NTC coefficient which is never given.**  So why do you need it when you have the curves on p 2,5?

Comment: very thanks for informations.I want to ask a more question.Datasheet has information of Iol (maximum overload current).if the current passes a little this value,what happens?

Comment: Never exceed max inrush current or Overload rating Iol

Comment: For UL approval l: Iol max. x 0.85 rating !!!  Choose a different design.

Comment: Then why are this thermistors  in 265 volt category?For a ptc R25=18 ohm,265/18=14.72 A But inrush current: 1 A. Why?

Comment: YOu must have a series load to prevent the 14.72A or a much bigger Voltage rating  PTC style

Comment: What is your load ?  DCR?  uF , ESR  ? Vp ? Joules?  I surge, I trip, Ihold?  Perhaps what you need is an NTC ICL surge limiter

Comment: https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/ametherm/MS22-12104/570-1006-ND/749846

Comment: yes ı have series load.I want to use overload protection ptc.Total current 15 a.Resistance of ptc should be smaller than 4-5 ohm for leave cold series load.I think,I should parallel connection.But switching time is important and I can't simulate ptc in proteus.Anyway.
So,Is in datasheet Iol overload current rms value or dc value ?

Comment: If your question is just about Proteus. Call them with your license #.  If it is about design, insufficient info on real-time impedance to reply.

Comment: I think,according to my calculations I need to 11 ohm x 5 piece ptc but overload current of every ptc should be 2.6 amper-3.0 amper.But I haven't found.Thanks for your replys

Comment: Your requirements indicate it must dissipate 11Ohms * 3A^2= 100W which cannot be done in a tiny part.  Define your load better then voltage and max current to design a better solution

Comment: I want to ask 2 more questions.
1)If R=11 ohm in 25 °C and Iolmax =1500 (max overload current),then How can i calculate lolmax in 50 °C ?What is the formula?

2)If R=11 ohm in 25 °C,then how can i calculate R in 50 °C and in other tempratures?What is the formula?